# Unhandled Rejection undefined is not an object error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React. When I run the program I get this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'labels.labels.map')

I guess is that as getLabels is a promise, labels is undefined when I try to set state. If it is, it's weird because the same steps I do with tickets.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const tickets = await api.getTickets({page: this.state.pageNumber});
        const labels = await api.getLabels();

        this.setState({
            tickets: tickets.paginatedData,
            hasNextPage: tickets.hasNextPage,
            labels: labels.labels.map(name => ({ title: name , selected: false}))
        });
    }
```

here is the server side code

```
export const createApiClient = (): ApiClient => {
    return {
        getLabels: () => {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:3232/api/labels').then(res => res.data);
        }
    }
}
```

```
app.get('/api/labels', (req, res) => {

    const labels = Array.from(new Set(tempData.map((ticket: any) => ticket.labels).flat(1))).filter(l => l != null);
    res.send(labels);
});
```

Comment: Sounds like `getLabels` does not return an object with a `labels` property

Comment: it returns, I logged it out, it is not empty

Comment: Doesn't sound like it - please create a [MCVE]

Comment: i've edited the question, hope it's detailed enough

Answer (score 0):

api result of `lables` itself is an arry and it doesn't have property `labels` in it to access `labels.labels`.

you need to map label directly like `labels.map()` instead of `labels.labels.map()`

And any async function need to wrap async calls in try catch block to handle failure cases.

```
async componentDidMount() {
      try{
        const tickets = await api.getTickets({page: this.state.pageNumber});
        const labels = await api.getLabels();

        this.setState({
            tickets: tickets.paginatedData,
            hasNextPage: tickets.hasNextPage,
            labels: labels.labels.map(name => ({ title: name , selected: false}))
        });
      }

     catch(err){
       //handle err here
     }
}
```